# Syntax error "Missing operator" on simple update query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables.

Table 1:

| ID | Color | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | red | It's red |
| 2 | blue | yeah |
| 3 | blue | blue |

Table 2:

| ID | Family |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | family1 |
| 2 | family1 |
| 3 | family2 |

I want to dissolve table 2 and just add the `Family` column to the end of my table 1. Easy, right? So I add a family column to table 1 and

```
UPDATE table1 
    SET Table1.family = table2.family
FROM
table1 INNER JOIN table2 
    ON table1.ID = table2.id;
```

I get

> Syntax Error : Missing operator.

Isn't this the syntax for these types of queries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MS-Access syntax for a joined update is as follows:

```
UPDATE table1 INNER JOIN table2 
ON table1.ID = table2.id
SET table1.family = table2.family
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the wrong syntax, for Access use:

```
UPDATE table1 INNER JOIN table2 
      ON table1.ID = table2.id
SET Table1.family = table2.family;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id 
SET table1.family = table2.family;
```